# Div not showing

Tags: html, css

I want to make my friend's website, I want to make buttons and the div im using is not showing. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code.

```css
.box {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #2650ff;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

**PS : Fixed**

Comment: The div probably has 0 height since it has no content, if that's all of the code.

Comment: What is the size of your div?

Comment: If there is no content then add a height for div

Comment: `<div class='box'>try this now</div>` This will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #2650ff;
  height: 100px;  /* or whatever you want the height set at */
}
```

it seems you have nothing in the Div container. If the div is empty, the height collapses and is not viewable. simply place text, icon, img, or button within the div and that item will become visible. If you want it to remain empty, just set a static height for the div in the css.

Comment: I see no output here

Answer (score 0):

Your div is empty please add text to div and style to your button.

```css
.box {
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color:#2650ff;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='box'>content text</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Calling DIV text a "button" will confuse a clearly beginner level coder. Edited.

Comment: P.S position is not at all important to fix their actual issue.